# In Linux, what program is responsible for DNS lookups?

Tags: networking, dns, protocols

As a way to test out some of my ideas for DNS stuff, I wrote a *very* simple server that basically emulates a DNS-like behavior by basically responding to key-value pairs.

I could easily write a client to this server in C that would perhaps take in a hostname as a parameter and print out an IP (or something of the sort)

My real question is in a linux scenario, what piece of code is ultimately responsible for lookups. How does this program operate? Would it be trivial to overwrite this program with a custom "toy" client (in a VM, of course)?

Of course, this is all theoretical, I have no plans of using this outside of a virtual machine, and more so, I don't want to implement the default DNS protocol (so simply setting the DNS server setting to localhost or 127.0.0.1 wouldn't be of use to me)

Some sample code on the kind of behavior I'd like to implement (psuedo)

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(strcmp(argv[0], "localhost") == 0){
           printf("127.0.0.1");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let me make sure I understand - you want to rewrite your OS's DNS client, so that it resolves names using your own protocol and server?

Comment: yeah. I mean, it's not supposed to be, well.. smart in anyway, but I want to be able to type in fake.name into the web browser and have it resolve without hosts file or anything

Comment: `resolver(3)`, and it uses `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: You can install an actual DNS process and edit it to whatever you want.

Comment: @mbratch How might I go about overwriting it?

Comment: Under Linux, you could get the kernel source where you'll find the DNS resolver functions and rewrite them to your liking. Then rebuild and re-install the kernel.

Comment: @mbratch There is no DNS component in the kernel. The (3) in *resolver(3)* means it is a library function, not a system call which would be (2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that is responsible for performing name lookups is not a program as such, it's a library: the name service switch, which is a component of libc.

The name service switch supports pluggable backend modules, so if you don't want to use DNS, you can write your own name service switch (NSS) backend. Under Linux and glibc, NSS backend modules are named something like `/lib/nss_<name>.so.2`. You configure the NSS to tell it what backend you want to use by editing `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Typically two backend are used for hosts: `files` (looks up names in `/etc/hosts`) and `dns` (looks up names in DNS).

There is some quite sparse documentation on how to write an NSS module in [glibc's manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Extending-NSS.html) but it is probably possible to find a better tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!